# Multiple DBs from a single Rails app: what's the state-of-the-art?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-migrations, multiple-databases

After doing some research, it seems as though Rails has explicit, elegant support for multiple DB connections: http://www.rubynaut.net/articles/2008/05/31/how-to-access-multiple-database-in-rails.html

However, rails seemingly has nonexistent support for supporting this in migrations: http://www.jamesinman.co.uk/2011/10/serving-one-rails-application-with-multiple-databases/

So a few projects have come up to fill in the blanks. example: http://kovyrin.github.com/db-charmer/

Am I missing something here? It's odd that connecting to multiple databases is easy and elegant, but migrating them requires hacking.

Comment: Hmmm, never crossed my mind.  I have rails apps with a local database, that they run migrations for, and other connections to databases which are legacy or management by a different app, that I would never need to run migrations.  Running migrations between two or more databases is like having multiple local databases, and I don't see why you would need that instead of one database with all your local data.  But that's just me.  I never considered this as a question.

Comment: In order to segment data for scalability.

Comment: Sure, I was just explaining my experience, which might shed light on why it was hard to find a provided solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

Ah, it's quite simple actually :-D

In Rails 3:

```
class CreateAPIRequestLogs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def connection
    SpecialClassWithAlternativeDB.connection
  end

  def change
    # ... your migration code ...
  end
end
```

However it looks like rollbacks don't work properly.

Also, the schema version is still kept in the primary database.